# onKeyEntered never called

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

im my code I expect to get posts from my firebase database, but the onKeyEntered never called, to check if there is a problem in my code I wrote some toasts to check that, but I found that the onQueryReady is called as expected but the problem is in onKeyEntered, I even made the location static on a specific post's location, actually there are lots of posts with this location, but it still the same and the onKeyEntered never called. please some help.

```
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        posts = new ArrayList<>();

        //initialization work of the recycler view
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.posts_fragment, container, false);

        //initialization work of the firebase database
        firebaseInitializationWork();

        return recyclerViewInitializationWork(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        geoQueryToSearchPosts.addGeoQueryEventListener(geoQueryEventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        geoQueryToSearchPosts.removeAllListeners();
    }

    private void firebaseInitializationWork() {
        if (posts == null)
            posts = new ArrayList<>();
        //setting up the reference and the geoquery objects
        postsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");
        geofireToSearchPosts = new GeoFire(postsReference);

        //set the query on the current location and around the user with 1 kilo meter.
        updateLocation();
        geoQueryToSearchPosts = geofireToSearchPosts.queryAtLocation(
                /*getLastKnownLocation()*/new GeoLocation(29.9061584,31.2710861), 1);

        //creating the listener and adding it to the geoQueryToSearchPosts.
        attachTheGeoQueryListener();

    }

    private GeoLocation getLastKnownLocation() {
        GeoLocation geoLocation = null;
        /*if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        }*/
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps");
        geoLocation = new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude() , location.getLongitude());
        return geoLocation;
    }

    //function to initialize the geofire query listener
    //and attach it to the geofire query object (geoQueryToSearchPosts)
    private void attachTheGeoQueryListener() {
        if (geoQueryEventListener == null) {
            geoQueryEventListener = new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity() , "onKeyEntered" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //retrieving the post by listening on the post node.
                    postsReference.child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            //adding the post to the array.
                            posts.add(0, (PostDataClass) dataSnapshot.getValue());

                            // notifying the adapter that there is
                            //an element inserted.
                            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
                            //scroll to the beginning of the list
                            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(String key) {
                    postsReference.child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            //deleting the post from the posts array and notify the adapter that
                            //the post the postion has been deleted.
                            PostDataClass post = (PostDataClass) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            int postPosition = posts.indexOf(post);
                            posts.remove(post);
                            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(postPosition);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity() , "onGeoQueryReady" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity() , "onGeoQueryError" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };
            //geoQueryToSearchPosts.addGeoQueryEventListener(geoQueryEventListener);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: To improve the chances of anyone being able to help, reduce the code to the [minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful).

Comment: Cross-post: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/issues/67

Comment: can you help me, please with this code. I have already reduced it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my problem,the problem was that I'm listening to the posts node not the geofire node,so it doesn't see any location to be entered my area of concern.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue... trying to add marker to my google map onKeyEntered... I added runOnUiThread in the onKeyEntered method..

```
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(final String key, GeoLocation location) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Key Entered");

            TrackOrderFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    mDriverMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(carIcon))
                            .position(selectedDriver)
                            .title(key));
                    mDriverMarker.setTag(key);
                }
            });



        }
```

}

Really hope it works for you... Thanks